# Is there an extension or option in Firefox for getting the IP of a host and then visiting the IP instead of the host?

Tags: firefox, dns, ip, firefox-extensions

Let's suppose you don't have access to `www.site.com`, but if you open the IP of the site in Firefox instead of the host name, you can access without problems.

**Is there an extension or something in Firefox, that before accessing a page, gets its IP and queries the IP instead of the host?**

**Or maybe a software in Windows?**

I cannot use same IP all the time, because the IP changes during the day...

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a plugin, though you can always do it the slow way and bookmark the ip of e.g. http://domaintoip.com/ip.php , then search the ip and click the resulting link.

But, why can't your computer resolve IP's to domain names? This sounds like a bad problem.

Comment: Of course my computer can, but I'm under a proxy and sometimes I get blocked when the hostname belongs to a list ;) and that doesn't happen with IPs... so I need to query the IP instead of the hostname. Your solution is better than mine :) (I always 'ping' the machine, copy & paste the IP and click on Enter)

Comment: oh I understand now... haha, using proxy is a pain, I remember having the same problem and just gave up. But glad that link was useful.